# ASP.NET WebAPI FromUri URL Limit

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

I have a WebAPI method which takes in 3 parameters, two of them primitive data types and the 3rd one is a complex data type:

```
public HttpResponseMessage validateUser(string elementName, string checkPermission, List<AccessElement> accessGroups)
```

I'm making call to this WebAPI using Angular `$http`:

```
  return $http({
            method: 'get',
            url: serviceUrlPrefix + '/api/v1/validateUser',
            params: { 'elementName': CONSTANTS.UNAUTH_DATA_UI, 'checkPermission': CONSTANTS.CAN_READ , 'accessGroups': accessGroups }


        })
```

**Problem:**
When `$http` request is made, the query string values are truncated as the complex datatype parameter `accessGroups` is relatively long. I read in one of the blogs that query string limit in IE is 2083 characters

**Question 1:**
In my scenario, I won't say that `acessGroups` object is too big as it is a collection of 10 records (having 4 columns). With the query string limit on each browser, its quite understandable that I would face this truncation very easily when we pass the complex data type. So if it is the case, I would like to understand what is the primary use of `[FromUri]`.

**Question 2:**
I was able to get around this issue by making the controller method as

```
public HttpResponseMessage validateUser(string elementName, string checkPermission, [FroimUri]List<AccessElement> accessGroups)
```

And made a POST call to this method with "data" parameter

```
 return $http({
            method: 'post',
            url: serviceUrlPrefix + '/api/v1/validateUser',
            params: { 'elementName': CONSTANTS.UNAUTH_DATA_UI, 'checkPermission': CONSTANTS.CAN_READ },
            data: { 'accessGroups': accessGroups }

        })
```

What is the drawback in this approach, since I'm going for "POST" method from a normal "Get". Would it cause any additional overhead?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the only drawback is not adhering to the `REST` design principles (`POST` should be used to create a resource according to `REST` paradigm).
In practical terms, I would use `[FromBody]` tag. That way, you can be certain you won't run into any length restrictions.